# Page is not loading when redirect from another page in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a React application that starts with the login page. When the login button is clicked on the login page, I want it to redirect to the home page. I want to be redirected to the notifications page as soon as I go home page. So the routing operations are as follows:

- / -> /login
- /login -> /home
- /home -> /notifications

But when I click to login button, it goes home page and then notifications page but although I see the path as http://localhost:3000/#/notifications, page is not loading. And nothing on the page console.

And my code:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {HashRouter, Redirect, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.scss';

const loading = () => <div className="animated fadeIn pt-3 text-center">Loading...</div>;
const DefaultLayout = React.lazy(() => import('./containers/DefaultLayout'));

// Pages
const Login = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/Login'));
const Register = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/Register'));
const Page404 = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/Page404'));
const Page500 = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Pages/Page500'));

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
          <React.Suspense fallback={loading()}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/login" name="Login Page" render={props => <Login {...props}/>} />
              <Route exact path="/register" name="Register Page" render={props => <Register {...props}/>} />
              <Route exact path="/404" name="Page 404" render={props => <Page404 {...props}/>} />
              <Route exact path="/500" name="Page 500" render={props => <Page500 {...props}/>} />
              <Route exact path="/" name="Login" render={props => <Login {...props}/>} />
              <Route path="/home" name="Home" render={props => <DefaultLayout {...props}/>} />            
</Switch>
          </React.Suspense>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Card, CardBody, CardGroup, Col, Container, Form, Input, InputGroup, InputGroupAddon, InputGroupText, Row } from 'reactstrap';

class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleOnClick = this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
  }


  handleOnClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
      this.props.history.push('/home');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
        <Container>
          <Row className="justify-content-center">
            <Col md="8">
              <CardGroup>
                <Card className="p-4">
                  <CardBody>
                    <Form>
                      <div >
                        <img style={{marginBottom:15}} src={'../../img/HvlLogo.jpg'} alt={'aa'}/>
                      </div>
                      <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                        <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                          <InputGroupText>
                            <i className="icon-user"></i>
                          </InputGroupText>
                        </InputGroupAddon>
                        <Input type="text" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı" autoComplete="username" />
                      </InputGroup>
                      <InputGroup className="mb-4">
                        <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                          <InputGroupText>
                            <i className="icon-lock"></i>
                          </InputGroupText>
                        </InputGroupAddon>
                        <Input type="password" placeholder="Şifre" autoComplete="current-password" />
                      </InputGroup>
                      <Row>
                        <Col xs="6">
                          <Button color="primary" className="px-4" onClick={this.handleOnClick}> Giriş</Button>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Form>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
                <Card className="text-white bg-primary py-5 d-md-down-none" style={{ width: '44%' }}>
                  <CardBody className="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <h2>Buraya sitenin kisa aciklamasi girilecek,</h2>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                        labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </CardGroup>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

**defaultLayout.js**

```
import React, { Component, Suspense } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as router from 'react-router-dom';
import { Container } from 'reactstrap';

import {
  AppFooter,
  AppHeader,
  AppSidebar,
  AppSidebarFooter,
  AppSidebarForm,
  AppSidebarHeader,
  AppSidebarMinimizer,
  AppBreadcrumb2 as AppBreadcrumb,
  AppSidebarNav2 as AppSidebarNav,
} from '@coreui/react';
// sidebar nav config
import navigation from '../../_nav';
// routes config
import routes from '../../routes';

const DefaultFooter = React.lazy(() => import('./DefaultFooter'));
const DefaultHeader = React.lazy(() => import('./DefaultHeader'));

class DefaultLayout extends Component {

  loading = () => <div className="animated fadeIn pt-1 text-center">Loading...</div>

  signOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.history.push('/login')
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="app">
          <AppHeader fixed>
            <Suspense fallback={this.loading()}>
              <DefaultHeader onLogout={e => this.signOut(e)}/>
            </Suspense>
          </AppHeader>
          <div className="app-body">
            <AppSidebar fixed display="lg">
              <AppSidebarHeader/>
              <AppSidebarForm/>
              <Suspense>
                <AppSidebarNav navConfig={navigation} {...this.props} router={router}/>
              </Suspense>
              <AppSidebarFooter/>
              <AppSidebarMinimizer/>
            </AppSidebar>
            <main className="main">
              <AppBreadcrumb appRoutes={routes} router={router}/>
              <Container fluid>
                <Suspense fallback={this.loading()}>
                  <Switch>
                    {routes.map((route, idx) => {
                      return route.component ? (
                          <Route
                              key={idx}
                              path={route.path}
                              exact={route.exact}
                              name={route.name}
                              render={props => (
                                  <route.component {...props} />
                              )}/>
                      ) : (null);
                    })}
                    <Redirect exact from="/home" to="/notifications"/>
                  </Switch>
                </Suspense>
              </Container>
            </main>
          </div>
          <AppFooter>
            <Suspense fallback={this.loading()}>
              <DefaultFooter/>
            </Suspense>
          </AppFooter>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DefaultLayout;
```

**routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const Alerts = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Notifications/Alerts'));
const Badges = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Notifications/Badges'));
const Modals = React.lazy(() => import('./views/Notifications/Modals'));

// https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config
const routes = [
  { path: '/', exact: true, name: 'Login' },
  { path: '/home', exact: true, name: 'Home'},
  { path: '/notifications', exact: true, name: 'Notifications',component: Alerts },
  { path: '/notifications/alerts', exact: true,name: 'Alerts', component: Alerts },
  { path: '/notifications/badges', exact: true,name: 'Badges', component: Badges },
  { path: '/notifications/modals', exact: true,name: 'Modals', component: Modals },
];

export default routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

use *BrowserRouter* instead of *HashRouter*